# I would like to retrive history words from an online dictionary webpage with Python 3.2 urllib

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I am using [tureng](http://tureng.com) online dictionary for Turkish-English / English-Turkish translation and this webpage records word search history and I would like to retrive these words with this code

```
import urllib.request
f = urllib.request.urlopen("http://tureng.com/history/details")
text=f.read().decode('utf-8')
#print(text)

start = text.find("<span class=\"historyTerm\"><a href=\"/search/")
```

I know how to parse the searched word afterwords however the problem is that while retriving the page source with urllib, I can't see my searched  words. It says "there are no history records for this day". So how can I solve this problem?

If you view the page source after searching a few words, you can see  [tureng history words](http://tureng.com/history/details)

Here in my browser, I can see the searched words:

[image: turenginbrowser]

Here in python:

[image: turenginpython]

Answer (score 1):

When you're looking up for words and translations, I suppose that you're using your web browser. The website you're using should store the history of lookup inside a cookie or in the cache of your browser. When your calling the URL using your python script, it's the same as opening a new web browser with a clean session.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve those with Python?

Comment: Your program would need to do the work in 3 steps: 1 - query the website, 2 - parse the return cookie , 3 - claim the history while passing the cookie in you request. You can see what are the values stored in the cookies by using Firebug (a Firefox extension). BTW you're sure that the site you're using does not provide a nice API because web scraping can be quite boring (IMHO).

Comment: I have added here http://tinypic.com/r/2vkj24l/6 a screen cap of the cookie the browser is passing when you make a GET on history/details, as you cna see the previous searches are stored.

Comment: You can find the "history" of search in the response cookie when you're issuing a search: http://tinypic.com/r/2epog9i/6

Answer (score 0):

The question contains the answer actually. You can simply click to "Export to Excel" button which will give all the data you need as a simple excel file :-)